# OpenCV Live Stream from Camera in Django webpage with image details

Tags: python, django, opencv

I am making a project in Django. And have made live feed from camera on a webpage. I am also processing the video to detect faces, and gestures. But I am not able to send the array (i.e which contains the features of videos like face detected or not, hand gesture, etc) to the template.

**Views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import StreamingHttpResponse
from streamapp.camera import VideoCamera
from django.http import HttpResponse


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        feature = camera.render_features()
        print(feature)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


def video_feed(request):
    return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'streamapp/home.html')
```

**Urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from streamapp import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('video_feed/', views.video_feed, name='video_feed'),
    ]
```

In View.py line number 10, **feature** is the array that I want to access inside the webpage(home.html).
How to pass that array to the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return the frame to bytes before passing the frame, `frame.tobytes()`

In your HTML file add this code to request for the streaminghttpresponse from the views.py

```html
<body>
    <img src="{% url 'video_feed' %}" width="20%">
</body>
```